# SQL subquery with join to main query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
SELECT 
SU.FullName as Salesperson,
COUNT(DS.new_dealsheetid) as Units,
SUM(SO.New_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) as TDP,
SUM(SO.New_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) / COUNT(DS.new_dealsheetid) as PPU,

-- opportunities subquery
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Opportunity O
LEFT JOIN Account A ON O.AccountId = A.AccountId
WHERE A.OwnerId = SU.SystemUserId AND
YEAR(O.CreatedOn) = 2022)
-- /opportunities subquery

FROM New_dealsheet DS
LEFT JOIN SalesOrder SO ON DS.New_DSheetId = SO.SalesOrderId
LEFT JOIN New_salespeople SP ON DS.New_SalespersonId = SP.New_salespeopleId
LEFT JOIN SystemUser SU ON SP.New_SystemUserId = SU.SystemUserId
WHERE 
YEAR(SO.New_purchaseordersenddate) = 2022 AND
SP.New_SalesGroupIdName = 'LO'
GROUP BY SU.FullName
```

I'm getting an error from the subquery:

> Column 'SystemUser.SystemUserId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Is it possible to use the SystemUser table join from the main query in this way?

Comment: SystemUser.SystemUserId is not in the select in the published query so the publihed query can't have cause that error. NB As a correlated sub query it looks ok

Comment: The answer is in the error message.  You should add SU.SystemUserId to the GROUP BY

Comment: It's in the correlated subquery, @P.Salmon , so it *is* in the `SELECT`, just the `WHERE` clause of the correlated subquery in the `SELECT`. The above *can* generate the error.

Comment: @Larnu I see that but in a where clause so why would it complain about that?

Comment: Because of the correlation, @P.Salmon . `A.OwnerId = SU.SystemUserId` has an outer reference to `SU.SystemUserId`, so it's referencing the table `SystemUser` in the main query's `FROM`. As such, that column is part of the aggregate query with a `GROUP BY` clause and/or aggregation, and all columns referenced in the `SELECT` (which it is in) *must* be either aggregated or grouped on. Presumably `SystemUserId` is a Primary key, and so adding it to the `GROUP BY` won't affect the groupings (well, it might if 2 or more people have the same name, which isn't uncommon).

Comment: On a separate note, why do you use `LEFT JOIN`s here when it is **mandatory** that both `SO.New_purchaseordersenddate` and `SP.New_SalesGroupIdName` have non-`NULL` values. It is *impossible* for a column to have a non-`NULL` value if no row was found. In addition, syntax like `YEAR(SO.New_purchaseordersenddate) = 2022` in the `WHERE` is not advisable; this causes the query to be non-SARGable and thus will perform poorly. If you want every row for a specific year, then use a date range, don't use `YEAR` (or other functions) on your columns in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned extensively in the comments, the error is actually telling you the problem; `SU.SystemUserId` isn't in the `GROUP BY` nor in an aggregate function, and it appears in the `SELECT` of the query (albeit in the `WHERE` of a correlated subquery). Any columns in the `SELECT` *must* be either aggregated or in the `GROUP BY` when using one of the other for a query scope. As the column in question isn't aggregated nor in the `GROUP BY`, the error occurs.

There are, however, other problems. Like mentioned ikn the comments too, your `LEFT JOIN`s make little sense, as many of the tables you `LEFT JOIN` to *require* a column in that table to have a non-`NULL` value; it is **impossible** for a column to have a non-`NULL` value if a row was not found.

You also use syntax like `YEAR(<Column Name>) = <int Value>` in the `WHERE`; this is not SARGable, and thus should be avoided. Use explicit date boundaries instead.

I *assume* here that `SU.SystemUserId` is a primary key, and so should be in the `GROUP BY`. This is probably a good thing anyway, as a person's full name isn't something that can be used to determine who a person is on their own (take this from someone who shared their name, date of birth *and* post code with another person in their youth; it caused many problems on the rudimentary IT systems of the time). This results in a query like this:

```sql
SELECT SU.FullName AS Salesperson,
       COUNT(DS.new_dealsheetid) AS Units,
       SUM(SO.New_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) AS TDP,
       SUM(SO.New_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) / COUNT(DS.new_dealsheetid) AS PPU,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Opportunity O
             JOIN dbo.Account A ON O.AccountId = A.AccountId --A.OwnerID must have a non-NULL value, so why was this a LEFT JOIN?
        WHERE A.OwnerId = SU.SystemUserId
          AND O.CreatedOn >= '20220101' --Don't use YEAR(<Column Name>) = <int Value> syntax, it isn't SARGable
          AND O.CreatedOn < '20230101') AS SomeColumnAlias
FROM dbo.New_dealsheet DS
     JOIN dbo.SalesOrder SO ON DS.New_DSheetId = SO.SalesOrderId --SO.New_purchaseordersenddate must have a non-NULL value, so why was this a LEFT JOIN?
     JOIN dbo.New_salespeople SP ON DS.New_SalespersonId = SP.New_salespeopleId --SP.New_SalesGroupIdName must have a non-NULL value, so why was this a LEFT JOIN?
     LEFT JOIN dbo.SystemUser SU ON SP.New_SystemUserId = SU.SystemUserId --This actually looks like it can be a LEFT JOIN.
WHERE SO.New_purchaseordersenddate >= '20220101' --Don't use YEAR(<Column Name>) = <int Value> syntax, it isn't SARGable
  AND SO.New_purchaseordersenddate < '20230101'
  AND SP.New_SalesGroupIdName = 'LO'
GROUP BY SU.FullName,
         SU.SystemUserId;
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing such a sub-query is bad on a performance-wise point of view

better do it like this:

```
SELECT 
SU.FullName as Salesperson,
COUNT(DS.new_dealsheetid) as Units,
SUM(SO.New_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) as TDP,
SUM(SO.New_profits_sales_totaldealprofit) / COUNT(DS.new_dealsheetid) as PPU,

SUM(csq.cnt) as Count

FROM New_dealsheet DS
LEFT JOIN SalesOrder SO ON DS.New_DSheetId = SO.SalesOrderId
LEFT JOIN New_salespeople SP ON DS.New_SalespersonId = SP.New_salespeopleId
LEFT JOIN SystemUser SU ON SP.New_SystemUserId = SU.SystemUserId

-- Moved subquery as sub-join
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.OwnerId, YEAR(o.CreatedOn) as year, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Opportunity O
LEFT JOIN Account A ON O.AccountId = A.AccountId
GROUP BY a.OwnerId, YEAR(o.CreatedOn) as csq ON csq.OwnerId = su.SystemUserId and csqn.Year = 2022
WHERE 
YEAR(SO.New_purchaseordersenddate) = 2022 AND
SP.New_SalesGroupIdName = 'LO'
GROUP BY SU.FullName
```

So you have a nice join and a clean result
The query above is untested

Comment: This will generate a similar error, however, this time it would be *"Column '
csq.cnt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."*

Comment: Also. you say that the subquery is "bad for performance" but you don't address that *main* cuprits for the poor performance; the non-SARGable `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Well a select in the select-part of a query is o^n notation, so that clearly is bad. Yes, you're right the query still produces some issues (and can be optimized) we're not here to write code for others but to help fix a problem. Doing this with a join is way better than a sub-query

Comment: But this query has the *same* problem, but with a different column name... Replacing a faulty part in a car with another faulty part isn't fixing the problem; the same applies here.

Comment: *"we're not here to write code for others but to help fix a problem"* Just "fixing the problem" and taking the time to also explain what other problems there are is what makes the difference between an answer, a *good* answer and a **great** answer. For an answer that explicitly mentions performance, leaving the main culprit for the poor performance is an "odd" choice.

Comment: is the sargable problem using more performance than the o^n sub-query? I didn't know that particular stuff. Yes you're right, the answer was not perfect - i changed the query to get rid of the where condition inside the join - still there is a year-part. How could you fix that? By giving the full-date and join with a between? As there is a group by the count sould also be summarized then.

Comment: The problems in the `WHERE` clauses are going to cause full scans of the tables, so yes, that are must certainly going to be a bigger contributor here.

Comment: totally feasible, one question, I often need to group data by year and month. So using GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) will be non-sargable. Any idea how to avoid that? Is this just not possible and I have to live with the performance-loss?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` isn't a filter predicate, so won't affect the SARGability.